# Why am I not able to debug Silverlight in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, debugging, silverlight, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

I keep receiving the following error when attempting to step through the C# silverlight code in Visual Studio 2015- “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”.

I have tried the following to no effect:

- set the Silverlight Debugging checkbox on the project properties Web tab
- checked the debug constant and trace constant
- ensure debug configuration, debug flag, and full debug info are set
- delete bin and obj folders
- disabled "just my code" in options > debugging
- set IE as my default browser
- checked to see if silverlight is attached in Attach to process

Any solutions, or possible ideas for why the debugger is not functioning? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if IE and VS are running under same user account. Use Task Manager to see this information.

Comment: @Mala, whether you have enabled the symbols server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols?

Comment: @SarveshMishra I checked and both IE and VS are running under the same user account.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT symbols server is enabled under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols. When I run my solution, I can see that it loads some symbols but I still run into the same issue and can't hit the breakpoints.

Comment: @Mala, Could you get useful information from Vladimir's suggestion? In addition, like the step2 here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2013/02/14/breakpoint-not-hitting-in-a-silverlight-ria-application/, is the Silverlight project tied to your Web project? The options ASP.NET should also be selected in your project property.

Comment: This one fixed my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534364/cannot-attach-to-silverlight-app-from-vs

Answer (score 2):

For me I was able to get debugging to work by:

1. Ensuring both ASP.NET and Silverlight were checked in my web project.
2. **Disabling** Tools > Options > Debugging > Just My Code.
3. **Loading all symbols** in Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols.

3 was the key for me.

Also, I checked "Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)" in order to have full debugging ability.

Comment: Just to add to this, since I've had this problem for a looong time and just came across this solution (which worked), **make sure you have your web project's start action set to "Current Page"**

Answer (score 1):

Delete Internet Explorer cache before starting a debug session. Sometimes this doesn't work so open your cache folder and delete all *.xap files manually. You can make a .bat file to do that before every debug session.