# Cannot attach to Silverlight app from VS

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, silverlight

In the past to connect to silverlight apps form Visual Studio I would go to Debug -> Attach To Process and then scroll down to where the type was Silverlight and attach to that.
Recently, silverlight types do not seem to show up in the attach to dialog.

**What I have tried**

- Project Properties -> Web -> Debuggers and ensure Silverlight is ticked
- Attaching to the same window as the silverlight is in

**What I want to happen**

To attach to silverlight apps from Visual Studio

**What is happening**

Silverlight apps do not show in the Attach To dialog

Comment: Do you use the VS2015? If yes, it really has no the Silverlight option in the attach to process window, but you could use the CoreCLR, as far as I know, attaching using CoreCLR allows debugging it as before.

Comment: Im using 2013.  The option use to be there

Comment: And there are no CoreCLR options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days I found a solution.

Go to Programs and Features and Uninstall ONLY "Microsoft Silverlight". Once uninstalled go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40633 and install either Silverlight_Developer.exe or Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe

This fixed the problem for me :)

Comment: Yep. I recently did creators update on my dev machine and encountered the same problem on VS2013. uninstalling and reinstalling silverlight fixed it for me as well. I've learned to do that Eevery time I update the OS .

Comment: @Tom Hanson, Glad to know that this issue has been resolved, if so, you could mark it as the answer later, so it could help other community members who meet the same issue as yours:)

Comment: @Tom Hanson, Thank you so much. This helped me.

Comment: GODSEND! Thanks so much. I've been unable to debug our legacy code for months